New Relic APM agent VS New Relic OpenTelemetry for Quarkus microservices monitoring and observability
I have a Quarkus application (consuming/producing messages from multiple Kafka topics) deployed on an AWS Kubernetes cluster. I want to monitor/observe my application. Right now, I am using the Quarkus OpenTelemtry library to send metrics to New Relic which is very straightforward (provide distributed tracing as well with Kafka events out of the box), but it doesn't contain JVM metrics and I can't create SLO for New Relic OpenTelemetry service, there are other features which are not available for OpenTelemetry but available with the Java agent.
Is there a way to get JVM metrics with OpenTelemetry? If not then will it be a good idea to move to java agent?
Please suggest which one should we go with, New Relic OpenTelemtry or New Relic Java agent.

you should be able to collect JVM, JMX metrics using opentelemetry too. You should look at https://github.com/SigNoz/signoz. You can try their cloud product https://signoz.io/pricing/ and since you have opentelemetry instrumented, you should be able to get started in a few minutes. You can import this dashboard to get JVM metrics https://github.com/SigNoz/dashboards/tree/main/jvm.
Ping me back here if there is some issue.
PS: I am one of the maintainers of SigNoz

It's a new tool right?, but our client has paid services for Newrelic, so was looking for solution related to that. but  I can try to propose this new tool as well.
Thank you :)

The New Relic Java agent is not compatible with native compiled Java. You don't specify in your question, but that is the case with many Quarkus apps.

@AndréOnuki yes, We are not using native mode of quarkus right now.

Yes, there is.
Metrics in Quarkus are currently implemented with Micrometer and you have an OTLP registry (HTTP protocol only) that you can use to send those metrics over.
The dependency from Quarkiverse: https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-micrometer-registry/dev/micrometer-registry-otlp.html
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkiverse.micrometer.registry</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-otlp</artifactId>
</dependency>

Also there are plans in the Quarkus roadmap around this area, on the Quarkus mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev/c/y5-ojIVsa_M/m/4wquJi4bBQAJ

I have tried this library , it says it sending the metrics but I don't see any JVM metrics on newrelic.
